# Share to facebook using angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

How do I share posts in facebook using angular controller?
Since angular uses # in its url, fb-share-button removes this # from its data-href preventing it to move to the controller. How do I use this dynamic link in fb share?

```html
<span data-href="#/share/{{post.id}}" class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count">
</span>
```

This # in the above line is removed by fb internally. How to share the link 127.0.0.1:8080/#/share/1  ?

Comment: You don’t. To share individual pieces of content, you need an individual URL for each such piece of content. (And if only the hash part differs, they are _not_ different URLs. The hash part is only of importance client-side.)

Comment: Any solution to perform such tasks?